# How to replace a number completly without modifying in the middle?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have `oldId` and `newId` and I want to replace `oldId` with `newId`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString = "{\"user_id\":{\"long\":876},\"client_id\":{\"int\":0},\"affinity\":[{\"try\":{\"long\":55787693},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.19}},{\"try\":{\"long\":1763},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.0114}}]}";

    // some other json strings -

    // String jsonString = "{\"user_id\":{\"string\": \"876\"},\"client_id\":{\"int\":0},\"affinity\":[{\"try\":{\"long\":55787693},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.19}},{\"try\":{\"long\":1763},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.0114}}]}";
    // String jsonString = "{\"user_id\": \"876\", \"client_id\":{\"int\":0},\"affinity\":[{\"try\":{\"long\":55787693},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.19}},{\"try\":{\"long\":1763},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.0114}}]}";
    // String jsonString = "{\"user_id\": 876, \"client_id\":{\"int\":0},\"affinity\":[{\"try\":{\"long\":55787693},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.19}},{\"try\":{\"long\":1763},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.0114}}]}";
    // String jsonString = "{\"user_id\": null, \"client_id\":{\"int\":0},\"affinity\":[{\"try\":{\"long\":55787693},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.19}},{\"try\":{\"long\":1763},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.0114}}]}";

    String newResponse = changeJsonString(jsonString, "876", "54321");
    System.out.println(newResponse);
}

private static String changeJsonString(String originalResponse, String oldId, String newId) {     
    return originalResponse.replaceAll(String.valueOf(oldId), String.valueOf(newId));
}
```

With the above code I have, it will print `newResponse` as -

```
{\"user_id\":{\"long\":54321},\"client_id\":{\"int\":0},\"affinity\":[{\"matter\":{\"long\":5575432193},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.19}},{\"try\":{\"long\":1763},\"scoring\":{\"float\":0.0114}}]}
```

If you see closely, two fields got change, one is `user_id` and second is `matter` since `replaceAll` will replace everything to a new one.

- user_id 876 got change to 54321
- matter 55787693 got change to 5575432193

What I am looking for is - It should only replace the full number to a new number instead of modifying any number in the middle to a new number. As an example - `user_id` `876` is a full number so it should replace `876` only to `54321` not`matter` in which 876 is in the middle.

In general, I want to replace a number to a new number completely. I don't want to replace something in the middle of it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: *edit* Use todd's approach :)

Comment: @user2469515 This will not work with my other jsonString which I have commented in my main method right?

Comment: 1. Use a JSON library to decode JSON into an object tree. 2. Change number in the object tree. 3. Use a JSON library to convert the object tree back to JSON.

Comment: @immibis I have tried using json library like GSON but when I try to read the data from GSON, it takes double for everything so my input values gets change and they have `.0` like this at the end.

Comment: @user2809564 if this is actually JSON (and not some mutant format that's almost but not quite like JSON), then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @immibis I see. Can you provide an example so that I can understand how to modify this correctly?

Comment: Doing this as string manipulation is a very dangerous plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lookbehind and lookahead to find the non-digit characters, because you don't want to replace them.  The syntax that you want, including the lookbehind and lookahead is this.

```
originalResponse.replaceAll("(?<=\\D)" + oldId + "(?=\\D)", String.valueOf(newId));
```

The syntax for a lookbehind is `(?<=X)` and for a lookahead is `(?=X)`, where `X` is an expression matching what you'll find behind or ahead.  The way to understand lookbehinds and lookaheads is that they mean "preceded by" and "followed by" respectively.

So `(?<=\D)876(?=\D)` means "find something that matches `876`, preceded by something that matches `\D` and followed by something that matches `\D`.  And of course, `\D` means any character that is not a digit.

But this expression is not the same as `\D876\D`, because the lookbehind and lookahead expressions aren't part of what gets replaced by the `replaceAll`.  We don't want the non-digit characters before and after the `876` to get replaced.

And of course, we escape the backslashes in a `String` literal by doubling them, so `\D` is written `"\\D"`.

Comment: I tried this and I got exception  - `Unknown look-behind group near index 4
(?<\D)876(?=\D)`. Not sure what does this mean

Comment: Ah, yes, I had a typo.  Can you try now?

Comment: looks like it works fine for my sample strings. let me do couple more tests. I am surprised how does this work and what it is doing? :)

Comment: Fair enough.  I will try to expand my explanation a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be to process JSON data as a JSON data.

Any string substitution or regex you employ would be fragile and could potentially break your code for some input JSON string. For example, what if, both `user_id` and `matter` values come in to be the same. Your assumption of not replacing in the middle simply fails then.

To process the JSON is just three lines of code:

```
private static String changeJsonString(String originalResponse, String newId) {     
    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(originalResponse);
        ((JSONObject) root.get("user_id")).put("long", Long.parseLong(newId));
        return root.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you wouldn't require `oldId` then. In case, your input string could contain multiple `user_id`s, you would simply extend my example to check and replace the appropriate `JSONObject`.

Please note that I'm using the [org.json.jar for Java](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/) from [www.json.org](http://www.json.org). You're free to use any JSON parser you like.

---

Since, you've re-posted this question but have provided the complete JSON string format there, I've proposed this solution [again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27915399/1237040) but with updates that handle all your possible JSON data types for `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In my case, that's what I need, I would like to replace all the fields which has oldUid value completely. If user_id and matter values are same, then in regex solution, both of them get replaced and that's what I want to do.

Comment: You're basically assuming that if your old `user_id` matches any JSON field completely then it must be referencing the same `user_id` value. That doesn't sound right. Are you absolutely sure that no other JSON field could ever have the same value? `client_id`, `try` or `scoring` etc. What if the structure undergoes a change later on and adds an `amount` field for example?

Comment: What I was saying is - Any field which has this `oldId` number, I want to replace it with newId. Whether it's a user_id field or try or scoring or amount. That's what I needed to do. Yes I agree, If I wanted to replace only user_id field, then yes regex solution was not good.